# How can I reliably get a Profile Trace for an Operation in Application Insights for an App Service?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, azure-application-insights, azure-application-insights-profiler

I am trying to performance profile a MVC5, C#, EF6 web app on Azure App Service.

I am using Application Insights. It is working. However when I click on a non performing "operation" for more investigation I rarely get a "profile trace" which I can use to get a "Hotspot Timeline", although I do get samples which I can drill into to get a database event Timeline. How can I reliably get this "profile trace"?

When I have found a "profile trace" I have found them to be quite systemy, rather than application centric with say method names.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

On the "End-to-end transaction details" / "Sample" Timeline I get time breaks/waits and I seem to have no way to identity what is going on in those gaps. Note from the legend image below one should be able to get "Profile Traces" in this timeline... but none available.

[image: Timeline legend]

A break/ wait where I have no idea of cause:

[image: Timeline wait/break with no reason as to why]

EDIT2:

Data sampling is currently set to 100%. Just gone into "Usage and Cost Estimation"